# Weaker condition for compact sets to be closed

Tags: general-topology, compactness

It's a very standard topological proof that in Hausdorff spaces compact sets are closed.  But is Hausdorff condition necessary, is there an example of topological space $X$ so that all compact sets are closed but space is not Hausdorff?  If yes, is there a weaker  condition which is necessary for all compact sets to be closed?

Comment: I don't understand the last sentence: do you want a *necessary* condition for the assertion "$X$ is a topological space such that every compact subspace is closed", or do you want a more general *sufficient* condition than being Hausdorff?

Comment: Compact does not imply closed in the line with two origins!  Take $[-1,1]$ with only one of the origins, and it is compact but not closed.

Comment: By "stronger" do you mean "weaker"? Any condition stronger than Hausdorff will work.

Comment: Spaces for which all compact sets are closed are  called kc (compact closed) spaces.  It is hardly a useful distinction.

Comment: @WilliamElliot  can you give example of kc space which is not hausdorff?

Answer (score 3):

In the classical paper [between $T_1$ and $T_2$](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2316017?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) Wilansky introduces the notion of a KC space:

> $X$ is called a KC space if every compact subset of $X$ is closed in $X$.

And as you note in the question, A Hausdorff ($T_2$) space is KC. And a KC space is clearly $T_1$ as all finite subsets are always compact and thus closed in a KC space.

The notion of US (unique sequential limits) is also introduced:

> $X$ is US iff for all sequences $(x_n)$ from $X$, if $x_n \to x$ and $x_n \to x'$ then $x=x'$.

And again $T_2 \implies US \implies T_1$ (for the latter consider constant sequences).

A KC space that is not Hausdorff is $\alpha\Bbb Q$, the Alexandroff extension (one-point compactification) of the rationals.

When such spaces are compact they turn out to be the maximally compact spaces, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2465585/4280), e.g. They're of some interest (look in Google scholar etc. for papers on them).